# Deploy a Azure Static web app with DevOps in a multi-stage pipeline

Tags: yaml, devops, azure-static-web-app, cicd

I'm currently developing a Blazor WebAssembly application that will be deployed on a Azure Static Web App. Now I need to create my CI/CD pipeline and there is a pretty easy way to build and publish the application using the AzureStaticWebApp task as shown here:

```
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      app_location: 'App.Web'
      app_build_command: 'dotnet build'
      api_location: 'App.Api'
      output_location: 'wwwroot'
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
```

This task however builds and releases the application at the same time. In my pipeline, I'd like to build my Blazor application and store it as an artifact. In one stage of my pipeline, this artifact will be published to a test environment and if all tests pass, then another stage will be to publish this same artifact to the production environment. The goal is to publish the exact same artifact that was tested on the production environment.

Is there a way to accomplish this using the AzureStaticWebApp task or is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can build the artifact in one job like this:

```html
  jobs:
- job: BuildWebsite
  displayName: Build website
  pool:
    name: $(azdoPool)
  steps:
  - checkout: self

             
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: npm install
    inputs:
      verbose: false

  - powershell: |
      npx gatsby build    
    displayName: build

  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: package artifacts
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/public/'
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: 'zip'
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(webPackageFile)'

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: publish website artifact
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(webPackageFile)'
      ArtifactName: $(artifactName)
```

(notice the publish to artifact in the last task)

and then test/deploy in another job:

```html
parameters:
  application: ''

jobs:  
- job: DeployStaticWebsite
  displayName: deploy 
  pool:
    name: $(azdoPool)
  steps:  
  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    displayName: Download $(webPackageFile)
    inputs:
      artifactName: $(artifactName)
      targetPath: $(artifactExtractPath)
      itemPattern: '**/$(webPackageFile)'

  - task: ExtractFiles@1
    inputs:
      archiveFilePatterns: $(artifactExtractPath)/$(webPackageFile)
      destinationFolder: $(artifactExtractPath)/extracted
    displayName: extract website

  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    displayName: Deploy App
    inputs:
      output_location: $(extractedZipPath)
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployTokenMercleCom)
      skip_app_build: true
```

Notice how the first task downloads the artifact/zip from the previous job.

these two jobs should be referenced by one or more stages in a different template file.  something like this:

stages:

- stage: Build
  displayName: Build
  jobs:

  - template: templates/build.yml
    parameters:
    application: ${{variables.environment}}
- stage: app1
  displayName: app1
  variables:
  application: app1
  deploymentToken: $(deployTokenApp1)
  jobs:

  - template: templates/deploy.yml
    parameters:
    application: ${{variables.environment}}
- stage: app2
  displayName: app2
  variables:
  application: app2
  deploymentToken: $(deployTokenApp2)
  jobs:

  - template: templates/deploy.yml
    parameters:
    application: ${{variables.environment}}

you can then keep adding stages for app3, app 4 as many as you want.  they can all deploy the same artifact that was originally built.  You'll also probably want to use deployment jobs if you want to add Environment approvals for each stage (so that you can preapprove each stage deployment).

Note, some of these variable in this yaml need defining before these template examples will run

Comment: Have you actually tested this? Specifically the last part of deploying from a package?